# Using Singleton Design Pattern In Swing

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I have been trying to develop swing application which contains **jxtreetable** in which i do have Jbutton(which is used for navigation to another frame for editing that particular record) 
previously i was just showing the window by creating new instance but later i realized that every time it opens new window (so if user clicked it 10 times then there will be 10 different window) so to avoid it i had implemented **singleton design pattern** which doesn't allow multiple window to opened
but at the same time if click on one edit button and then on another edit button it does refreshes the content within the frame on the first go but not on the second time

Edit Button is Jbutton which has been added to the jxtreetable column.

**is that thing happening due to reference is existed already ?how to workaround this?**

Comment: Some more context is needed. We don't know what kind of code your edit button calls, so it's sort of difficult to explain the behaviour. (As a side note, you can likely do without a singleton. Just store the reference to a field and check that for an already existing window before creating a new one).

Comment: uh, what edit button? I feel this question is like : Amy has 5 apples. Tony has 3 apples. Amy then gave Tony 2 apples. Now, how many apples does Jack have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do have `JButton`(which is used for navigation to another **frame** for
>   editing that particular record) previously i was just showing the
>   window by creating new instance but later i realized that every time
>   it opens new window **(so if user clicked it 10 times then there will be
>   10 different window)**

**Note:** remarks are mine.

There's no need to implement [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) here, it is intended to other purposes. You just need to read about Modality: **[How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).**

If the `JButton` is pressed don't show a new `JFrame` to edit the selected record but use a modal `JDialog` instead. This way the user won't be able to click the `JButton` again until this `JDialog` is closed. Consequently a single instance of the edit window will be shown, what is actually your goal.